# Sharepoint 2016 supports which version of visual studio?

Tags: 2016, visual-studio-2015

I have installed sharepoint 2016 in development environment and want to do custom development , which version of visual studio i need to install in dev environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio “15” Preview and Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 include new templates for developing SharePoint 2016 solutions and add-ins.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/26/the-latest-of-microsoft-office-developer-tools-office-add-in-commands-and-sharepoint-2016-support/